# CSV output file using command line for wireshark IO graph statistics

Tags: csv, wireshark, pcap, tshark

I save the IO graph statistics as CSV file containing the bits per second using the wireshark GUI. Is there a way to generate this CSV file with command line tshark? I can generate the statistics on command line as bytes per second as follows

tshark -nr test.pcap -q -z io,stat,1,BYTES

How do I generate bits/second and save it to a CSV file?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a way to do that using only tshark, but you can easily parse the output from tshark into a CSV file:

```
tshark -nr tmp.pcap -q -z io,stat,1,BYTES | grep -P "\d+\s+<>\s+\d+\s*\|\s+\d+" | awk -F '[ |]+' '{print $2","($5*8)}'
```

---

**Explanations**

- `grep -P "\d+\s+<>\s+\d+\s*\|\s+\d+"` selects only the raw from the tshark output with the actual data (i.e., `second <> second | transmitted bytes`).
- `awk -F '[ |]+' '{print $2","($5*8)}'` splits that data into 5 blocks with `[ |]+` as the separator and display blocks 2 (the second at which starts the interval) and 5 (the transmitted bytes) with a comma between them.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have been parsing the output with python script. I just wanted to know if it is possible only using tshark.

Comment: Not possible according to the documentation. I've checked only with Wireshark 2.2.6 though.

Comment: ok, then will accept this as an answer. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that may be good to know:

If you change the interval from 1 second to 0.5 seconds, then you have to allow `.` in the grep part by adding `\.` between two digits `\d` .

Otherwise the result will be an empty *.csv file.

```
grep -P "\d{1,2}\.{1}\d{1,2}\s+<>\s+\d{1,2}\.{1}\d{1,2}\s*\|\s+\d+"
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers in this thread gave me the keys to solving a similar problem with tshark io stats and I wanted to share the results and how it works. In my case, the task was to convert multiple columns of tshark io stat records with potential decimals in the data. This answer converts multiple data columns to csv, adds rudimentary headers, accounts for decimals in fields and variable numbers of spaces.

### Complete command string

```sh
tshark -r capture.pcapng -q -z io,stat,30,,FRAMES,BYTES,"FRAMES()ip.src == 10.10.10.10","BYTES()ip.src == 10.10.10.10","FRAMES()ip.dst == 10.10.10.10","BYTES()ip.dst == 10.10.10.10" \
| grep -P "\d+\.?\d*\s+<>\s+|Interval +\|" \
| tr -d " " | tr "|" "," | sed -E 's/<>/,/; s/(^,|,$)//g; s/Interval/Start,Stop/g' > somefile.csv
```

## Explanation

The command string has 3 major parts.

1. tshark creates the report with the data in columns
2. Extract the desired lines with grep
3. Use tr and sed to convert the records grep matched into a csv delimited file.

### Part 1: tshark creates the report with the data in columns

tshark is run with `-z io,stat` at a 30 second interval, counting frames and bytes with various filters.

```sh
tshark -r capture.pcapng -q -z io,stat,30,,FRAMES,BYTES,"FRAMES()ip.src == 10.10.10.10","BYTES()ip.src == 10.10.10.10","FRAMES()ip.dst == 10.10.10.10","BYTES()ip.dst == 10.10.10.10"
```

Here is the output when run against my test pcap file:

```
=================================================================================================
| IO Statistics                                                                                 |
|                                                                                               |
| Duration: 179.179180 secs                                                                     |
| Interval:  30 secs                                                                            |
|                                                                                               |
| Col 1: Frames and bytes                                                                       |
|     2: FRAMES                                                                                 |
|     3: BYTES                                                                                  |
|     4: FRAMES()ip.src == 10.10.10.10                                                          |
|     5: BYTES()ip.src == 10.10.10.10                                                           |
|     6: FRAMES()ip.dst == 10.10.10.10                                                          |
|     7: BYTES()ip.dst == 10.10.10.10                                                           |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|            |1                   |2       |3          |4       |5         |6       |7          |
| Interval   | Frames |   Bytes   | FRAMES |   BYTES   | FRAMES |   BYTES  | FRAMES |   BYTES   |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   0 <>  30 | 107813 | 120111352 | 107813 | 120111352 |  26682 | 15294257 |  80994 | 104808983 |
|  30 <>  60 | 122437 | 124508575 | 122437 | 124508575 |  49331 | 17080888 |  73017 | 107422509 |
|  60 <>  90 | 138999 | 135488315 | 138999 | 135488315 |  54829 | 22130920 |  84029 | 113348686 |
|  90 <> 120 | 158241 | 217781653 | 158241 | 217781653 |  42103 | 15870237 | 115971 | 201901201 |
| 120 <> 150 | 111708 | 131890800 | 111708 | 131890800 |  43709 | 18800647 |  67871 | 113082296 |
| 150 <> Dur | 123736 | 142639416 | 123736 | 142639416 |  50754 | 22053280 |  72786 | 120574520 |
=================================================================================================
```

#### Considerations

Looking at this output, we can see several items to consider:

- Rows with data have a unique sequence in the Interval column of "space<>space", which we will can use for matching.
- We want the header line, so we will use the word "Interval" followed by spaces and then a "|" character.
- The number of spaces in a column are variable depending on the number of digits per measurement.
- The Interval column gives both the time from 0 and the from the first measurement. Either can be used, so we will keep both and let the user decide.
- When using milliseconds there will be decimals in the Interval field
- Depending on the statistic requested, there may be decimals in the data columns
- The use of "|" as delimiters will require escaping in any regex statement that covers them.

### Part 2: Extract the desired lines with grep

Once tshark produces output, we use grep with regex to extract the lines we want to save.

```sh
grep -P "\d+\.?\d*\s+<>\s+|Interval +\|""
```

grep will use the "Digit(s)Space(s)<>Space(s)" character sequence in the Interval column to match the lines with data. It also uses an OR to grab the header by matching the characters "Interval |".

```
grep -P         # The "-P" flag turns on PCRE regex matching, which is not the same as egrep. With egrep, you will need to change the escaping.
 "\d+            # Match on 1 or more Digits. This is the 1st set of numbers in the Interval column.
 \.?             # 0 or 1 Periods. We need this to handle possible fractional seconds.
 \d*             # 0 or more Digits. To handle possible fractional seconds.
 \s+<>\s+        # 1 or more Spaces followed by the Characters "<>", then 1 or more Spaces.
 |               # Since this is not escaped, it is a regex OR
 Interval\s+\|"  # Match the String "Interval" followed by 1 or more Spaces and a literal "|".
```

From the tshark output, grep matched these lines:

```
| Interval   | Frames |   Bytes   | FRAMES |   BYTES   | FRAMES |   BYTES  | FRAMES |   BYTES   |
|   0 <>  30 | 107813 | 120111352 | 107813 | 120111352 |  26682 | 15294257 |  80994 | 104808983 |
|  30 <>  60 | 122437 | 124508575 | 122437 | 124508575 |  49331 | 17080888 |  73017 | 107422509 |
|  60 <>  90 | 138999 | 135488315 | 138999 | 135488315 |  54829 | 22130920 |  84029 | 113348686 |
|  90 <> 120 | 158241 | 217781653 | 158241 | 217781653 |  42103 | 15870237 | 115971 | 201901201 |
| 120 <> 150 | 111708 | 131890800 | 111708 | 131890800 |  43709 | 18800647 |  67871 | 113082296 |
| 150 <> Dur | 123736 | 142639416 | 123736 | 142639416 |  50754 | 22053280 |  72786 | 120574520 |
```

### Part 3: Use tr and sed to convert the records grep matched into a csv delimited file.

tr and sed are used for converting the lines grep matched into csv. tr does the bulk work of removing spaces and changing the "|" to ",". This is simpler and faster then using sed. However, sed is used for some cleanup work

```sh
tr -d " " | tr "|" "," | sed -E 's/<>/,/; s/(^,|,$)//g; s/Interval/Start,Stop/g'
```

Here is how these commands perform the conversion. The first trick is to get rid of all of the spaces. This means we dont have to account for them in any regex sequences, making the rest of the work simpler

```
| tr -d " "                 # Spaces are in the way, so delete them.
| tr "|" ","                # Change all "|" Characters to ",".
| sed -E 's/<>/,/;          # Change "<>" to "," splitting the Interval column.
  s/(^,|,$)//g;               # Delete leading and/or trailing "," on each line.
  s/Interval/Start,Stop/g'    # Each of the "Interval" columns needs a header, so change the text "Interval" into two words with a , separating them.
> somefile.csv              # Pipe the output into somefile.csv
```

### Final result

Once through this process, we have a csv output that can now be imported into your favorite csv tool, spreadsheet, or fed to a graphing program like gnuplot.

```
$cat somefile.csv
Start,Stop,Frames,Bytes,FRAMES,BYTES,FRAMES,BYTES,FRAMES,BYTES
0,30,107813,120111352,107813,120111352,26682,15294257,80994,104808983
30,60,122437,124508575,122437,124508575,49331,17080888,73017,107422509
60,90,138999,135488315,138999,135488315,54829,22130920,84029,113348686
90,120,158241,217781653,158241,217781653,42103,15870237,115971,201901201
120,150,111708,131890800,111708,131890800,43709,18800647,67871,113082296
150,Dur,123736,142639416,123736,142639416,50754,22053280,72786,120574520
```